# Existence of formula $\phi$ satisfying $\phi^M\to \mathrm{ZF}^M$ for every transitive proper class $M$

Tags: set-theory

I try to prove such exercise problem in Kunen:

> Let $M$ be a transitive proper class, then there is a finite conjunction $\phi$ of axioms of ZF, such that whenever $M$ is a transitive class which satisfy $\phi$, $M$ satisfies all axioms of ZF. (*Hint.* Apply IV 7.5. to the $M\cap V_\alpha$.)

where IV 7.5 is:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $Z$ is a class and $\langle Z_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha\in ON}$ is the increasing continuous sequence of sets satisfying $\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON} Z_\alpha=Z$ then for every formula $\phi$,
>   $$\forall \alpha\exists\beta>\alpha:\phi\text{ are absolute for }Z_\beta,\,Z.$$

I think that previous exercise is also a hint of the problem:

> (Previous exercise) There is a suitable finite subtheory $T$ of ZF, such that if a transitive proper class $M$ satisfies $T$ then $\forall x\subset M\exists y\in M:x\subset y.$

My attempt is: Let $\phi$ be the conjunction of pairing, union, power set and the (finitely many) axioms of $T$ mentioned above. If $\phi^M\to (\text{Comprehension})^M$ then we can conclude that $M$ is also satisfy replacement because of 'previous exercise'. The only problem is how to show that $\phi^M\to (\text{Comprehension})^M$. I guess that, for each comprehension axiom $\psi$ (note that comprehension is axiom scheme), there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that
$\forall\gamma>\alpha:\psi^{M\cap V_\gamma}.$ But I don't know how to proceed it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you know about Godel operations?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I heard about it but I do not learn about it because the book that I am using does not refer these operations. I try to prove the problem again.

Comment: Oh, I see it. Thanks for the help.